# Programmatically Add Products to Store View?

Tags: magento2, programmatically

We have a multi-store with a bunch of products.

For certain categories in specific store views, I'd like to set all products to be in a particular store. Advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

One of my biggest missing pieces is how to programmatically set the "Product in Stores" for each product -- I could probably figure out the rest from there. But yes, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: have u got solutions? programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily assign products to different stores from adminpanel. Go to products grid catalog->products
select all products or select selected products. Then click on actions dropdown from top left corner. Select Update Attribute then select websites. After that select specific store view's then save.

Comment: question was to add products programmatically. surprised to see this as an accepted answer.

Comment: That's fair @VishalParkash -- it solved my problem and I was grateful, so I probably got a little liberal with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of: If everyone every tries to google 'How to assign products to website or storeview programatically' Magento 1.9

Here's how, source from
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/Action/AttributeController.php`

Use

```
//...
$actionModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$productIds  = $this->_getHelper()->getProductIds();

if ($websiteRemoveData) {
    $actionModel->updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteRemoveData, 'remove');
}
if ($websiteAddData) {
    $actionModel->updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteAddData, 'add');
}

Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_to_website_change', array(
    'products' => $productIds
));
//...
```

Where the `$websiteAddData` and `$websiteRemoveData` is defined as followed

```
$websiteRemoveData  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('remove_website_ids', array());
$websiteAddData     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('add_website_ids', array());
```

Meaning, you will need to specify an array of website ids.